# How to express a parametric-function when there are same parameters in bounds and Integrand function of an integral?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I want to plot such a function:

```
m = {0.511, 105.67, 1776.8} 
g[x_] = 15/Pi^4*Integrate [Sqrt[u^2 - (m/t)^2] u^2/(Exp[u] + 1),{u, m/t, Infinity}]
Plot[g[x], {t, 10^3, 10^6}]
```

I just need three functions, but it turns out to be such a complex stuff. Functions can form a list by different values of parameter in the integrand function, but the parameter in integral bound still be an list. And perhaps because of so the curves can't be drawn.

[image]

Ps: when the parameter is just a constant value, it works just fine.

Comment: Look at your definition of g: `g[x_] = 15/Pi^4*Integrate [Sqrt[u^2 - (m/t)^2] u^2/(Exp[u] + 1),{u, m/t, Infinity}] Plot[g[x], {t, 10^3, 10^6}]`  This is not a function of "x".

Comment: I'm sorry for that mistake, but the result is the same when I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

m = {0.511, 105.67, 1776.8};

g[x_?NumericQ] :=
 15/Pi^4*NIntegrate[Sqrt[u^2 - x^2] u^2/(Exp[u] + 1),
   {u, x, Infinity},
   WorkingPrecision -> 15]

g[0]

(* 0.875000000014952 *)

Plot[Evaluate[g[#/t] & /@ m], {t, 10^3, 10^6},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, HoldForm@g[m/t]}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[m, LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[m], 14]],
   {.8, .4}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The limit of `g[m/t]` as `t -> Infinity`, i.e., `m/t -> 0` is

```
15/Pi^4*Integrate[u^3/(Exp[u] + 1), {u, 0, Infinity}]

(* 7/8 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It makes me realized how rough my code is...